# Powerbuilder - EAServer ORCA API Deployment

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy, easerver

I am facing an orca script deployment error. Orca returns error code -20. How can I solve this problem? BTW I can successfuly deploy my project using Powerbuilder IDE. System configuration: WindowsXP-32bit, Powerbuilder 11.2, EAServer 5.5. Below is the orca script output.

```
    Sybase (R) OrcaScript interpreter version 11.2
            Using ANSI source file deploy_file_name.orca.
    Start Session
    Set Liblist
             "path_to_pbl_1"
             "path_to_pbl_2"
             "path_to_pbl_3"
             "...other pbls..."
    Set Application "path_to_application_pbl" "target_name"
    Build Project "path_to_project_pbl" "project_name"
       Orca error in 'buildProject'. Result Code -20.
       Component builder initialization for project project_name failed
       An error occurred during initialization of the component builder class.
    Last Command Failed.
    End Session
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really test it now (no ORCA at home) but think the build project command needs at least two parameters pbl name and project name. Take a look here (Chapter 34):

http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-pb/pbg0900e/pbug/

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mistakenly wrote up there. Actual line was Build Project "path_to_pbl" "project_name". Anyway it has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: I give up then. I'have never seen -20 error code from ORCA. Maybe it is some kind of a DOS error (are you running this from a batch file somehow)?

Comment: I am running ORCASCR110 from command prompt, as it says in orcasript quick reference: ORCASCR110 [/D w:<variable>=sw:<value> ...] w:<batchfilename>

Answer (score 0):

Our script in PB10.5 follows the format below with all of the PBL's in the library list in a single string with semicolon's delimiting them.  We also provide the server name and server port in the `BUILD project` command.

```
start session
SET liblist "C:\AutoBuild\web_reports.pbl;C:\AutoBuild\jag_servermain.pbl"
SET application "web_reports.pbl" "reports_component"
BUILD project "web_reports.pbl" "p_d_webreport_impl" "jag_build" "9001"
end session
```

You may try that and see if it works for you.